# How to display error under UITextField in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

[image]
I want to show the error under an UItextfield and the border's color of the textfield turn into red.
How to do this? Thanks so much

Comment: What have you tried so far? It's not that hard. How do you usually display text. Do the same thing here as well. You can easily find out how to change the border color by googling.

Comment: you can do it by adding `UILabel` under `UITextField` like if your `UITextField` doesn't fullfil validation then set error text to `UILabel` or if it validate then set `""` text to `UILabel` or if you don't want to do this then there's number of ready libraries you can implement.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri Is it that simple. I just think of built-in function help me do this. Sorry, I'm just a beginner in Swift

Comment: @VũTinhPhan the above comment explains what you need to do. Although you could change the bit where he says keep the label always there. I would recommend that you add and remove the label when necessary.

Comment: @Kuldeep Thank you

Comment: I can answer your question if you promise to mark it as an approved answer :)

Comment: You can use the structure from my solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56742493/8551803

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Side Note*: You could use external libraries to do what I am about to show you. However, I believe that for someone new to Swift, this code can provide some insights on proper use of the language for mobile development. Also, excessive use of external libraries is often not good practice because your project will increase in size when more dependencies are added, making it slower to compile and take up more memory on the device. Whenever you can, you should use Swift's standard libraries and built-in functionality.

Ok, so we're going to have to setup an error message, first. This is easily done by creating a new `UILabel`. I don't know if you used storyboards to create your UI elements, but in the code below I just assume that you created everything programmatically.

Pay attention to how I add a **target** to `submitButton` to change `textField`'s and `errorMessage`'s appearance if a certain condition is not met (in this case, if `textField` is empty).

Also, notice how I use `UITextFieldDelegate`'s method `didBeginEditing(...)` to reset the `textField`'s border colour and hide `errorMessage` again.

```
class viewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    private let textField = UITextField()
    private let errorMessage = UILabel()
    private let submitButton = UIButton()

    override viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        /* setup your UI elements here */
        setupTextField()
        setupErrorMessage()
        setupSubmitButton()
    }

    func setupTextField() {
        /* setup your text field here (you did this already) */
    }

    func setupErrorMessage() {

        /* Here, I am using AutoLayout to lay out the errorMessage on the screen. 
           If you used storyboard, delete every line in this function except where 
           we set the message to hidden */

        errorMessage.translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        errorMessage.text = "Error Message"
        errorMessage.textColor = .red
        errorMessage.isHidden = true
        self.addSubView(errorMessage)

        NSLayoutConstraints.activate([
                    textField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textField.leadingAnchor),
                    textField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textField.bottomAnchor, constant: 10.0)
        ])
    }

    func setupSubmitButton() {
        /* setup your submit button here (you did this already) */
        submitButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(submitButtonPressed(_ :)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc func submitButtonPressed() {
        if textField.text.isEmpty {
            errorMessage.isHidden = false
            textField.layer.borderColor = .red
        }
    }

    /* use a UITextFieldDelegate method to change the textField's border color 
       to blue again after the user has corrected the mistake 
       (for example, after the user starts typing into the textField again) */
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        textField.layer.borderColor = .blue
        errorMessage.isHidden = true
    }
}
```